# In a querySaveDocument returns false how do I cause the Submit Action to return 'failed'

Tags: submit, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a regular submit button on a page with this code:

```
<xp:button value="Submit" id="button3" rendered="#{javascript:compositeData.dsEditBar.isEditable()}" styleClass="label">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
    refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:return 'success';
}]]></xp:this.action>
```

So it returns 'success' which I use in a Navigation Rule ,however, I have a querySaveDocument event that may return true or false. If it returns true return 'success' other wise return 'failed'. How do I capture the return from the QuerySave and pass that to the Navigation Rule?
Right now if the querySave fails it aborts the save and goes back to the view but I want to create a 'failure' Navigation Rule and display an error message in the same document.

Thanks

Comment: I think navigation will redirect the page, so you will loose data when not saved. Your querySaveDocument should be handled by validation, not navigation.

Comment: I don't think that would be a solution because of the nature of the things I need to do. I need to do a fair bit of processing. I guess I could do a computed field that would do what I need then set a field on the document to say true and have that a required field and must be true. Seems to me that I should be able to trap teh querySave return in the submit somehow. Maybe not.

Comment: From a bit of testing that I have done it would appear that the validation happens Before the querySaveDocument is triggered so if I set a value in the querySave it is too late for the validation.

Comment: You are right - validation occurs before action execution. I didn't mean validation as a phase. I meant "stay on the page with data and prevent redirect". That probably requires the change of your submit button to ordinary SSJS/simple actions.

Comment: Answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022953/sequence-of-events-from-a-submit-button