# Sequence of events from a submit button

Tags: submit, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a simple test page that I'm trying work through the sequence of events and how to handle a querySaveDocument failure.

As far as I can see the sequence of events is

1. onclick of submit
2. validation
3. querySaveDocument
4. save document

in the submit action I return 'success' but that happens regardless of whether the querySave returns true or false. Now what I want to do is if the querySave fails return tio the same document the same way as the validation does. So I believe that setting the return 'success' in the onclick event is what is causing the problem but how do I trap the querySaveDocument and if it fails just return otherwise do the 'success' navigation.

This should not be that difficult but I think it is because the querySaveDocument is a backend event. But I would think that this sort of process would be something that people would do pretty regularly. I want to do the querySave after the validation because there is no point in attempting to do a rather involved querySaveDocument event only if the document is ready to be saved.
I thought of doing the submit button return in an onComplete event but that does not appear to work. ??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.navigationRules>
        <xp:navigationRule outcome="success" viewId="xpMain.xsp">
        </xp:navigationRule>
    </xp:this.navigationRules>
    <xp:button value="Submit" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:println("In Submit")
return 'success';}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    Required Field&#160;
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.BusinessUnit}">
        <xp:this.validators>
            <xp:validateRequired message="Please enter a value"></xp:validateRequired>
        </xp:this.validators>
        <xp:this.required><![CDATA[#{javascript:println("In Validation");
return "This is a requiedd Field";}]]>
        </xp:this.required>
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument databaseName="Client Apps\LGI\LGI Rules.nsf"
            formName="frmCLRule" var="document1">
            <xp:this.querySaveDocument>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:println("In QuerySave");
return false;}]]>
            </xp:this.querySaveDocument>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i run the code, I see the order of execution is submit event, querySaveDocument and then navigation rule.

Use a viewScope variable in querySaveDocument event to record success or failure and then use that in navigationRule. Sample code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.navigationRules>
        <xp:navigationRule viewId="xpMain.xsp">
            <xp:this.outcome><![CDATA[#{javascript:if ( viewScope.qrySave ) {
    return 'success';
}}]]></xp:this.outcome>
        </xp:navigationRule>
    </xp:this.navigationRules>
    <xp:button value="Submit" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:println("In Submit")
return 'success';}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    Required Field&#160;
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{document1.BusinessUnit}">
        <xp:this.validators>
            <xp:validateRequired message="Please enter a value"></xp:validateRequired>
        </xp:this.validators>
        <xp:this.required><![CDATA[#{javascript:println("In Validation");
return "This is a requiedd Field";}]]>
        </xp:this.required>
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument databaseName="Client Apps\LGI\LGI Rules.nsf"
            formName="frmCLRule" var="document1">
            <xp:this.querySaveDocument>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:println("In QuerySave");
viewScope.qrySave = false;
//viewScope.qrySave = true;
return false;}]]>
            </xp:this.querySaveDocument>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: That works great passing the viewScope works like a charm. Git it working  now!